# How do I change on click color of the comment field of my wordpress blog with css?

Tags: css, wordpress, background-color

So, I am an absolute beginner, using self hosted wordpress and started out with the baskerville 2 theme, which I edited through the "additional css" field wordpress provides in its customization tab.

Basically, I am attempting to change the color of all these boxes to a different colour, let's just say pink, when I click into them to write. I just don't know what to put into the css field.

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hwpas.png)
this is what the comment/email boxes looks like. They are just white. (Ignore the pink one)

when I click into the field it will turn a dark blue color. I tried to inspect and find the color to then change it in the css editor but I just could't find it.
[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I75cG.png)

Lets assume I wanted to get the color to change to pink when clicking into any of these field instead of dark blue.

I searched Google and tried to put

```
#respond input[type=text], textarea {
background-color: pink;
}
```

as I read it in another forum, but as you can see in the pictures above it changed the colour of one random box to pink and it stays pink, no matter if I click on it or not. It did nothing to the other boxes or to the color when I click into a box.

I also tried to change the color, background or background-color of

```
.comment-form textarea {
div#respond textarea {
.comment-form p {
```

and some other comment-form elements I could find but none of them changed the color the way I was looking for.

I also couldn't find a specific tutorial for this.

I am not too tech savvy as you might be able to tell, sorry, so I hope you can understand what I mean :/
Maybe one of you even knows this wordpress comment form already and can help me out. :)

Comment: If you want to change the background color to pink on focus (when you click in it) you can use for the first element (which is a textarea, the second element wich is input probably type text and the third which is probably type email: textarea:focus, input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="email"]:focus {
  background: pink;
} Also note that you might need to add !important as it is wordpress like this {background: pink !important;} to overwrite wordpress styling

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I added 
    .comment-form input[type="text"]:focus, .comment-form input[type="email"]:focus, .comment-form input[type="url"]:focus, .comment-form textarea:focus, div#respond textarea:focus {
 background-color: pink !important;
}    
and it worked :)

Comment: Glad that it helped! enjoy coding!